# Subtotals with ArrayFormula()

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I've created a simple table and trying to split data with subtotals.

[image]

- A indicates the subtotal lines.
- B contains the rows number for previous subtotal. This is just extra field to simplify formulas.
- C Contains some amounts.
- D Contains subtotals of amounts between previous and current subtotal line.

The subtotal formula has the following view:

```
=ArrayFormula(
    IF($A2:$A; MMULT(
        ($B2:$B < TRANSPOSE(ROW($A2:$A))) * (TRANSPOSE(ROW($A2:$A)) < ROW($A2:$A)); 
        IF(ISNUMBER(C2:C); C2:C; 0)
    ); )
)
```

The problem is that the formula is extrimely slow. Is there a way to make it faster?

Example file:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HPGeLZfar2s6pIQMVdQ8mIPzNdw2ESqKAwZfo4IicnA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try this much simpler formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(
   if(B3:B="","",
         sumif(row(B3:B),"<="&row(B3:B),C3:C)-
         sumif(row(B3:B),"<="&B3:B,C3:C)
   )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I like this formula. It is simple and fast)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is

The easier is to remove the blank rows below the data range.

One that might require maintenance, replace open reference like `$A2:$A` by closed references, i.e. `$A2:$A100`

One that incresase the formula complexity an volatility, put each open reference inside `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` but it's easier to maintain in case that new data rows were added

Answer (score 0):

use the "necessary" range:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(A2:A; MMULT((
 INDIRECT("B2:B"&MAX(IF(B2:B="";;  ROW(B2:B)))) < TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(IF(A2:A=TRUE; ROW(A2:A); )))))) * (TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(IF(A2:A=TRUE; ROW(A2:A); ))))) < ROW(
 INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(IF(A2:A=TRUE; ROW(A2:A); ))))); IF(ISNUMBER(
 INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(IF(C2:C="";;  ROW(C2:C)+1)))); 
 INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(IF(C2:C="";;  ROW(C2:C)+1))); 0)); )))
```

this should be way faster...

[image: 0]